# best online services for i18n localization of existing rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, translation, i18n-gem

**Whats your opinion on translation services and which one would be a good fit for rails project with 2,3 but growing number of languages?**

Perhaps we can compile a list of services with pro's and con's.

I have looked at:

- http://www.localeapp.com ( very nice but a bit pricey above the 500 + strings )
- https://webtranslateit.com
- http://www.smartling.com
- http://99translations.com

Any recomendations on what service would be a good fit ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need an affordable solution, you might want to take a look at PhraseApp as well: https://phraseapp.com

Comment: payed but seems best solution out there yes

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at CopyCopter? It was commercial service, but it turned into open source project. You have nice screencast on railscasts on the topic: http://railscasts.com/episodes/336-copycopter

Comment: Yes, but that is not for translating I18n strings, its for managing content as a whole